# uploading a csv file in pandas python in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

I want to upload a csv file in pandas.
Here is the code :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
print(df)
```

I tried it with different files, too.
The csv file and the py file are located in the same location,
but every time this error pups up:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)

I tried the file location in `read_cvs()` too, but nothing changed.

and i tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas
and also tried with putting csv file in all files like venv
but nothing changed
i tried the code and the csv file in  visual studio code and it worked,
but i want it in pycharm

Comment: Can you show us the tree of your directory?

Comment: If the file exists, I would suggest uninstalling and installing Pandas

Comment: Are you doing thin in .env?

Answer (score 0):

In your error, it shows that the error is coming from circular imports. Uninstall pandas using `pip uninstall pandas` and then install it with `pip install pandas`. Furthermore, read [this article on circular imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) and how to deal with them.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, just to make sure he did not uninstall a package used by pandas

Comment: nothing changed , the code and the csv file work in visual studio code, but i need in pycharm

Comment: It is probably your pycharm environment, switch to your main environment and then try